# How can I add a posting limit to a Flask forum website?

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to limit the posts per hour a user can make in order to avoid spam? I've thought of making it based on cookies or IP address, but I haven't had any luck finding examples of how to do it that way.

EDIT: I want to keep it anonymous, so there will be no registered users.

Comment: If you don't have anonymous users (and each user is tracked), you can make it based on user_id or whatever.

Comment: rate limiting is typically something done at the load balancer or webserver level. It would help if you could tell us more about your infrastructure.

Comment: I want to keep it anonymous, so I've left out the ability to register users.Also, I'm using mongoDB and planning on doing the same once I start testing it on Heroku. I've only used mongoDB and sqlite3 so far, but I'd be happy to try something else since this is my first large web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a database that stores the the post data, including the name of the poster and the timestamp, you can create a class that can determine if the user is posting at a valid time:

```
import re, itertools, sqlite3
class Posts:
   def __init__(self, _username[str, int], _rate = 5) -> None:
      '''rate: number of posts per hour'''
      self.username = _username
      self.rate = _rate
   def __bool__(self):
      '''assuming database has columns "author" and "timestamp"
         timestamp: mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss
      '''
      data = list(sqlite3.connect('filename.db').cursor().execute("SELECT author, timestamp from TABLENAME"))
      user_posts = [re.findall('\w+/\w+/\w+\s\d+', b)[0] for a, b in data if a == self.username]
      if not user_posts:
        return True
      groups = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(user_posts)]
      return len(groups[-1]) < self.rate
```

Then, in the app, on a route such as `/post_article`:

```
@app.route('/post_article', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_article():
  if flask.request.method == 'POST':
     poster = Posts(flask.session['current_user'])
     if not poster:
      return '<p>Posting limit exceeded. Try again soon</p>'
     #take in user form data and update db
     return flask.redirect('/new_article_name')
  return flask.render_template('post_article.html')
```

Comment: I'm forgot to mention that there will be no registered users. Even so, this still works if I create a 'user_id' cookie(if there isn't one already) the moment someone tries to submit a new post, right?

Comment: @NamelessAI I would generate the cookie when the user first accesses the page. Then, commit the username into the database when the user first posts an article. If you create a new cookie the moment a submission attempt is made, it would erase the original user session value should the poster at that moment be a returning user. More to the point, this answer will work as long as you are using and maintaining a database that stores at least the timestamp and poster_name/poster_id.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep dragging this, but i want to make sure I've got it right because I'm new to the web dev side of Python. It goes: create cookies when user lands on the website(user_id) even though they won't register/login, add timestamp and user_id attributes to Post class, check user's latest timestamp(based on user_id) when creating a new post, raise an error if not enough time has passed since last post or allow post submission and make that timestamp the user's new timestamp.

Comment: @NamelessAI No problem. What you detailed above should work, but note that you cannot raise an error (`raise SomeError`), as that will crash your app. Rather, return a bit of HTML detailing the time violation, or redirect to another part of the page.